# If exit(0) is there before return 1, will return1 execute?

Tags: c, return, exit

What happens in the follwing code, does program executes 'return 1' or exits before?

```
int cmd_quit(tok_t arg[]) {
  printf("Bye\n");
  exit(0);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why should `return 1;` be executed before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit()` ends the program, no matter what. So: no. In practice, a C runtime will always do something similar of

```
exit(main(argc, argv));
```

to execute your program.

(meaning: **if** `main()` returns, `exit()` will be called automatically with its return value)

Comment: Could there be any use of writing both in any case (without any condition like if  else)?

Comment: @UtkarshGupta No. The only job of `exit()` is ending your program *here and now*. If you're at the end of `main()`, just return the return code, the runtime will call `exit()` (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The program will exit before encountering the `return 1;` statement.

Answer (score 1):

- The [`exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) function causes process termination.
- The `exit()` function does not return.
- Your program will not reach `return 1`;

Answer (score 0):

The function `exit` will be executed before `return` but it is usually used for an abnormal exit and returns a failure code to the caller. So it would be better to reverse the exit values

```
exit(1);
return 0;
```

But in the code you provide, it would make sense to detect an actual failure.

```
if (printf("Bye\n") <= 0)
    exit(1);
return 0;
```